# Laravel validation with custom json respons

Tags: json, laravel, validation

Quick question. 
Would it be possible to changes the JSON validation response of laravel?
This is for a custom API that I am building in Laravel.

Validation process

```
$validation = $this->validate( 
    $request, [
        'user_id' => 'required', 
    ]);
```

The response shows up like this in json

```
{
  "message": "The given data was invalid.",
  "errors": {
    "user_id": [
      "The user id field is required."
    ],
  }
}
```

Preferable it would become something like this.

```
{
    "common:" [
        "status": "invalid",
        "message": "Param xxxx is required",
    ],
}
```

What would be the best way to changes this? 
Is it even possible?

Thank you.

Comment: why you want to change this ? you can manage it in front end. as laravel returns all errors at once for an elements. and in your format it is just one.

Comment: Its for a custom api function that returns json. The meaning is to get a certain template with json format

Comment: also reformat your expected result from current resonse what you need exactly? and yes please explain why you need this ?

Comment: can you show your code where you returns laravel validation messages?

Comment: Right now laravel does the validations by itself the following way. $validation = $this->validate(
            $request, 
            [   
                'user_id'             =>        'required',
            ] 
        );

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this, and it will be reflected globally.
Navigate to below folder and use Controller.php
app/Http/Controllers

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Write below method in Controller.php and change response as you want.

```
public function validate(
    Request $request,
    array $rules,
    array $messages = [],
    array $customAttributes = [])
{
    $validator = $this->getValidationFactory()
        ->make(
            $request->all(),
            $rules, $messages,
            $customAttributes
        );
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $errors = (new \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException($validator))->errors();
        throw new \Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException(response()->json(
            [
                'status' => false,
                'message' => "Some fields are missing!",
                'error_code' => 1,
                'errors' => $errors
            ], \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY));
    }
}
```

I have tried it with Laravel 5.6, maybe this is useful for you.

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for this. What if I only want to show one error? is this also possible? Like the validations are user_id, and username, but I they are both missing I only want to show an error for the user_id and not the username.

Comment: @WesleySchravendijk, you can use `bail` rule to the attribute.

Comment: I have tried the bail function, but somehow it doesn't work in laravel 5.7. For example; 'user_id'             =>        'bail|required',

Comment: it does not work using laravel 8, I added the code in Controller.php and nothing worked

Answer (score 6):

I was searching for an answer to this and I think I found a better way. There is an exception handler in a default Laravel app - `\App\Exceptions\Handler` - and you can override the `invalidJson` method:

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    // ...

    protected function invalidJson($request, ValidationException $exception)
    {
        $errors = [];
        foreach ($exception->errors() as $field => $messages) {
            foreach ($messages as $message) {
                $errors[] = [
                    'code' => $field,
                    'message' => $message,
                ];
            }
        }
    
        return response()->json([
            'error' => $errors,
        ], $exception->status);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Dev Ramesh solution is still perfectly valid for placing inline within your controller.

For those of you looking to abstract this logic out into a [FormRequest](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#creating-form-requests), `FormRequest` has a handy override method called `failedValidation`. When this is hit, you can throw your own response exception, like so...

```php
/**
 * When we fail validation, override our default error.
 *
 * @param ValidatorContract $validator
 */
protected function failedValidation(\Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator $validator)
{
    $errors = $this->validator->errors();

    throw new \Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException(
        response()->json([
            'errors' => $errors,
            'message' => 'The given data was invalid.',

            'testing' => 'Whatever custom data you want here...',
        ], 422)
    );
}
```